# set of string to be search in another set

Tags: algorithm, scala

What is the best way to search a group of sentences in a larger predefined group of sentences?

Larger predefined groups of sentences can hold 20000 sentences and one sentence may constitute of maximum 250 characters.

There is a scenario where the size of both become the same.

My Approach -
Stored both the groups in a list. Used binarysearch from java api.

Comment: You can use a HashMap or a HashSet.

Comment: And what do you need? Check if set A is entirely contained in set B, check if at least one element of A exists on B, get the intersection? get the asymmetric difference?, etc? - Also, do you need the solution in **Scala** or in **Java**? _(you tagged both)_. Finally, what did you tried?

Comment: @olivier did you mean keys of hashmap as strings and values as null.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Scala uses the JVM so I guess the standard Java API can be used in Scala.

Comment: You should use a HashSet if you don't need to associate anything to a sentence.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez in scala i need solution. one set of string comes as input from customers which can be at most 20000 and the output which i get hitting third party application has strings. I need to show only those strings in output which matches from those i get in input.

Comment: @Olivier yeah, but nobody does that unless you need to interact with legacy Java code, that is why I am asking if op requires the solution in plain Scala or if in plain Java or if a mix of both.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez it should be in scala. i have to make sure that search is faster to ensure in does not break SLA for expected o/p time with client.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
val customers: Set[String] = Set(
  "Luis",
  "Oliver",
  "abhi"
)

def thirdPartyService(): List[String] =
  List(
    "Luis",
    "Miguel",
    "Oliver"
  )

val result = thirdPartyService().filter(customers)
// result: List[String] = List(Luis, Oliver)
```

Or, if you can get the result from the third party service also as a **Set**, you can do this:

```
val customers: Set[String] = Set(
  "Luis",
  "Oliver",
  "abhi"
)

def thirdPartyService(): Set[String] =
  Set(
    "Luis",
    "Miguel",
    "Oliver"
  )

val result = thirdPartyService() & customers // Also known as intersect.
// result: Set[String] = Set(Luis, Oliver)
```

*(in any case, make sure to check the [**scaladoc**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set.html) next time, you will find it has a lot of useful methods)*